# Duda sobre función exponenciadora

Tags: c, funciones

Tengo este codigo en lenguaje C, pero estoy tratando de comprenderlo muy bien.Alguien me podria explicar como funciona la funcion de  "int exponente" porque no entiendo mucho la lógica. gracias

Realiza una función que eleve un número a un exponente cualquiera.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int exponente();
int main(){
int num;
int ex, res;
printf("Digite un numero cualquiera:");
scanf("%i", &num);
printf("Digite el exponente el cual desea elevar el numero previo:");
scanf("%i", &ex);
res=exponente(num,ex);
printf("\n El numero escogido %i , elevado al exponente escogido es: %i \n", num, res);


system("pause");
return 0;
}

int exponente(int x, int y){
int z=1 , i;

for(i=1; i<=y; i++){
    z=z*x;
    
}


return (z);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal vez no se le entiende porque tiene malas prácticas de programación, es decir, el código debería poder explicarse a si mismo y no usar nombres de variables como "z", o "a":

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>


int exponente(int base, int _exp); //  Este es el prototipo, que le dice al compilador
                                   //+ información sobre los valores que la función
                                   //+ acepta y regresará
int exponente(int base, int _exp) {
    /*Multiplica la "base", "_exp" veces y regresa
    el resultado.
    
    Ejemplo: _exp = 3, base = 2, i = 1.
    Osea, "base" (2), se multiplicará "_exp" (3) veces
    acumulador = 1*2 = 2, i=1
    acumulador = 2*2 = 4, i=2
    acumulador = 4*2 = 8, i=3
    
    regresa acumulador, con valor de 8, osea, 2*2*2
    */
    int acumulador = 1;

    for(int i=1; i<=_exp; i++)
        acumulador*=base;

    return acumulador;
}

int main() {
    int numero;  // Este será la base, osea, el número elevado a una potencia
    int _exp;    // Esta será la potencia a la que el número anterior será elevado

    printf("Digite un numero cualquiera:");
    scanf("%i", &numero);  // almacenamos el valor de la base en la variable "numero"
    printf("Digite el exponente el cual desea elevar el numero previo:");
    scanf("%i", &_exp);  // Almacenamos el valor del exponente en la variable "_exp"
    
    // Mandamos a llamar a la función exponente y almacenamos su regreso
    // en la variable del mismo tipo "resultado"
    int resultado = exponente(numero, _exp);

    printf("\n El numero escogido %i, elevado al exponente escogido es: %i \n",
        numero, resultado);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Documentacion de microsoft para C:
[Documentacion C](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/cpp/c-language/functions-c?view=msvc-170)

Es una función que retorna un integer y también recibe dos integers `int x, int y`, pasa por un for que itera las veces que indique el valor 'y', dentro de este for 'z' se reasigna siendo igual a su número actual multiplicado por el valor x. Ej:

con `x=5,y=3` :

```
z = 1 * 5 = 5
z = 5 * 5 = 25
z = 25 * 5 = 125
```

Después, retorna ese valor z

Comment: No existe una documentación oficial de C o C++ como tal. Esa es **la documentación de Microsoft para C** y tiene mayor peso si estás usando el compilador de Microsoft. La mayor autoridad sería el estándar de C (ISO 9899).

Comment: Tienes razon lo modificare